# Setting cookies from a api on a different domain on Azure

Tags: azure, cookies, session-cookies

I have a `apiapp` in azure that the `webapp` is calling. I have the `apiapp` setting cookies on the `webapp` for state, this all works fine when its the same domain but im moving to Azure App Services and the cookies are coming back in the headers with the domain set but nothing is being displayed on the cookies tab in chromium. Both sites are Https ... is it perhaps that CORS is setup wrong. I am using Node for the api if that means anything and right now i have the domains in the below screen shots hard coded.

The api app has the CORS origin set to `https://ep-webapp.azurewebsites.net` in app services.

The locale cookie is being set by the `webapp`

So... is this even possible .. is there a better way to do this

[image: Header Response]

[image: Cookies not set]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to route the calls in Azure using a reverse proxy...

https://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/

> WEBSITE_PRIVATE_EXTENSIONS set to 1 in the App Settings for the site.

```
    <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^api/?(.*)"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://apiapp.azurewebsites.net/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
```